# Pulling Dependency from Bintray

Tags: java, android, bintray

[image]I recently updated my android studio to version 3.0 and I have an android library I needed to update and as well upload to bintray.

I was able to upload the library, but pulling the library from the repository prove abortive.

I have checked the path to the library and it actually exist in the remote repo, which underscore the possibility of the library not existing in the remote bot the pom file and the aar exist upstream.

I have spent more than neccessary time on this. I will appreciate any help in the right direction

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of your bintray page after clicking on the lastest version

Comment: @capt.swag, I have added the screenshot